# Angular 2 - Variable dinámica en un Componente

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, typescript, system.js

Estoy tratando de realizar un Componente en Angular 2. Este componente tiene una variable `title`, cuyo valor se muestra en una parte del template :

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

declare var ol: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'map',
  template: `
  <div id="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <strong class="navbar-brand">{{title}}</strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="down" #mapa style="max-height : 500px;">
    </div>
  </div>
  `
})
class MapaComponent {
  @ViewChild('mapa') mapa;
  map  : any;

  title : string = 'Mi mapa';

  /* Contructor */
  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.map = new ol.Map({
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
      ],
      target: this.mapa.nativeElement,
      view: new ol.View({...})
    })
  }
}

bootstrap(MapaComponent, []); // Component is bootstrapped!
```

Lo que quiero llegar a hacer es modificar el valor de dicha variable para cada componente creado y estaba pensando en si se podría hacer de alguna manera declarando el valor de dicha variable como atributo de un `Component` de la siguiente forma :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mapa</title>
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/build/ol.js"></script>

    <script>
      System.import ('built/map')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Componente creado -->
    <map title = "Mapa A"></map>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">


  </body>
</html>
```

**¿Es posible modificar el valor de la variable title de esta forma?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

debes de utilizar la siguiente clase ElementRef y así lo utilizas.

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prueba</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
    </head>
    <body id="homepage">

        <div class="home-panel" id="panel-main">
            <params-app valor="4">Loading...</params-app>
        </div>

        <!--<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>-->
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

angular.ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'params-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/src/cuadro.html'
})

export class AppComponent  {
    valor: number;

    constructor( public elementRef: ElementRef ){
        let native = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        this.valor = native.getAttribute("valor");
        console.log( "valor", this.valor );
    }

}
```

Esto solo lo debes de utilizar con los "componentes" que inician la aplicación , ya que con los componentes hijos si funcionan el metodo que colocastes anteriormente, la clase ElementRef podría causarte problemas de seguridad en tu aplicación web, checa el links siguientes para mas información.

[Link API angular 2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html)

[Documentación del problema](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858#issuecomment-151326461)

Otra solución que puedes hacer es la creación de un componente hijo y así evitas utilizar clases inseguras

index.html( sin muchos cambios )

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Prueba</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
    </head>
    <body id="homepage">

        <div class="home-panel" id="panel-main">
            <params-app>Loading...</params-app>
        </div>

        <!--<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>-->
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

inicio.ts ( Mandamos a llamar nuestro nuevo componente llamado MapasComponent )

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MapasComponent } from './mapas';

@Component({
  selector: 'params-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/src/cuadro.html',
  directives: [MapasComponent]
})

export class AppComponent  {
    valor: number;
    opciones: string[] = ["America", "Asia"];

    constructor(){

    }

}
```

app/src/cuadro.html ( Enviamos las opciones al componente hijo )

```
<div class="container panel-head">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Ejemplo</h1>
        </div>
        <mapas-app [opciones]="opciones[0]"></mapas-app>
        <mapas-app [opciones]="opciones[1]"></mapas-app>
    </div>

</div>
```

mapas.ts ( Aquí creamos el componente de mapas, con el parametro "inputs" enviamos las datos )

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'mapas-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/src/mapas.html',
  inputs: ['opciones']
})

export class MapasComponent  {

    constructor(){
        //
    }

}
```

app/src/mapas.html ( imprimimos las opciones )

```
<p>Soy un mapa con opciones: {{ opciones }}</p>
```

Saludos!

Comment: Estaba pensando en algo así, cuando pueda comprobarlo te hago saber. Gracias!!